# Using the Baby-Step Giant-Step algorithm

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Here is a concept I am working through:

> As part of an attack on an El-Gamal cipher, solving the
>   discrete logarithm problem
>
> $$10^x = 532107 \;\, {\rm mod} \;\, 1313839.$$
>
> Using the baby-step, giant-step algorithm to find $x$.

I am struggling to find $x$ using the baby-step giant-step algorithm.

Here is roughly what I have been working with:

```
n = 1313839;
ls = {};
m = Round[Sqrt[n]];
b = 532107;
a = a;
For[k = 0, k <= 100, k++,
y = b;
ls1 = PowerModList[a, m - 1, n];
 If[MemberQ[{ls1}, y], ls = Append[ls, y]];
 If[MemberQ[{ls1}, y], Fail
  ];
 Print[ls]
```

I have not used PowerModList before, so I am not sure if that's the right choice here. My goal is to create a list of the elements given by a^0 through a^(m-1). Then I am trying to check if b is in the list, if it is not..this is the part I am stuck on.

Here is my updated code! I think it is working smoothly, however suggestions and tips for finesse would still be appreciated.

```
n = 1313839;
ls = {};
m = Ceiling[Sqrt[n]]
b = 532107;
a = PowerMod[10^m, -1, n];
y = b;
ls1 = Table[PowerMod[10, i, n], {i, 0, m - 1}];
While[! MemberQ[ls1, y], ls = Append[ls, y]; y = PowerMod[y*a, 1, n]];
ls = Append[ls, y];
r = Length[ls] - 1
s = Part[ls, r + 1];
z = Position[ls1, s];
x = r*m + (z - 1)
```

When checked. It does return:

```
PowerMod[10, x, n]
=532107
```

Comment: I suggest you never ever use `Mod[a^b, c]` but rather use `PowerMod[a, b, c]`.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Could you post your 'baby-step, giant-step' code in your question?

Comment: Sort of out of bounds for this site to have others code a homework solution.

Comment: How do I format my questions correctly with code? 
I have never used this website until tonight. Thank you!

p.s. Not my goal at all, Daniel! Thank you though for checking.

Comment: Consider using `Table` to generate a^0 through a^(m-1).

Comment: Here's a link to help you with formatting: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Thank you Chip, the Table command was helpful!

Comment: I think `PowerModList` is really intended for raising to fractional as opposed to integral powers. That's the case where a list of results makes sense; the integer case will have unique results.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick rewrite of your code.

```
CipherSolve[modulus_, b_] :=
   Module[{y = b, yList = {}, m = Ceiling[Sqrt[modulus]], pmod, modinv, z},
      modinv = PowerMod[10^m, -1, modulus];
      pmod = PowerMod[10, Range[0, m - 1], modulus];
      While[FreeQ[pmod, y],
         yList = Append[yList, y];
         y = Mod[y*modinv, modulus]
      ];
      z = Position[pmod, y][[1, 1]];
      Length[yList]*m + z - 1
   ]
```

- Variable `ls1` changed to `pmod`, `ls` changed to `yList` and initialized in Module, `a` to `modinv`, `m` initialized in Module
- `PowerMod` is Listable, so a Table is unnecessary
- `!MemberQ[pmod,y]` is the same as `FreeQ[pmod,y]`
- `PowerMod[y*modinv,1,modulus]` is the same as `Mod[y*modinv,modulus]`, no advantage
- Only interested in last value `y` of `yList`, so do not `Append`, adjust `Length` statements accordingly
- `Position` returns a nested list `{{z}}`, modify to just `z` by using `Position[pmod,y][[1,1]]`
- No need to assign a value to `x`, just return it from the function
- Warning: If there is **no** solution to $10^x\equiv b$, mod $n$, then this code loops endlessly!

Example,

```
CipherSolve[1313839, 532107]
(*  441720  *)
```

However,

```
CipherSolve[141, 125]
(*  never returns  *)
```

If you were not required to use the baby-step, giant-step algorithm, then there is a one-liner using `MultiplicativeOrder`:

```
MultiplicativeOrder[10, modulus, {b}]
```

When there is no solution, this function returns unevaluated, saving you from an infinite loop.

```
MultiplicativeOrder[10, 1313839, {532107}]
(*  441720  *)

MultiplicativeOrder[10, 141, {125}]
(* returns unevaluated *)
```

Comment: `modinv = PowerMod[10, -m, modulus]` would be slightly neater. The `While[]` loop can be redone to use `NestWhile[]` instead.